# Magento 2: Showing error on production mode

Tags: magento-enterprise, fatal-error, production-mode, magento2.3.5

I'm facing an issue like errors are show on PRODUCTION mode, how can this be possible. Anyone have any idea how can this be resolved?

[image]

Comment: Best way to not get errors in production mode is to not have errors at all. :)

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore errors rather than fix them? Have we understood you correctly? Or are you asking how to fix this particular error?

Comment: We have a generated to check does production mode shows error or not

Comment: as Magento behaviour on production mode is it logs the error to file and show the log file name

Comment: the error should be logged in to log file instead of error is shown on the page.

Comment: So, I need to know is there any change in configuration or any file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be caused due to fault in files. So pls deploye contents and di compile . Then flush cache.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible can u check in your env.php file or can you flush your cache ?

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

update mode with developer mode check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html guideline for the same.

and than run following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Above command will show you list of errors you need to solve.

Comment: anything specific I need to check?

Comment: means its having developer mode or production mode ?

Comment: Its on production mode

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to belvg,

I had added local.xml to pub/errors which was printing the errors so I renamed the file and the issue was resolved.

for reference: https://belvg.com/blog/developer-mode-and-debugging-in-magento-2.html